# How to backup Thunderbird to mbox for use with the Pine or Alpine e-mail client?

Tags: text-processing, command-line, email, thunderbird, alpine-mail

How should the [mbox backup](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools-ng/) from Thunderbird show?  Perhaps there's a validation tool?

First screen:

```
  ALPINE 2.25   FOLDER LIST                                                                        Folder: baz(READONLY)                                                                        1 Message  

INBOX               sent-mail           saved-messages      22aug_saved         bar                 baz                 foo.mbox            foobar              sent-mail-aug-2022  sent-mail-dec-2022
sent-mail-may-2022  sent-mail-nov-2022  sent-mail-oct-2022  sent-mail-sep-2022
```

Second screen:

```
  ALPINE 2.25   MESSAGE INDEX                                                                  Folder: baz(READONLY)                                                                   Message 1 of 1 NEW  

  N   1 19:03      nicholas@mordor.saundersconsulting.tech                     (3M) /home/nicholas/mail/baz
```

Third screen.  Note that it's from the mordor FQDN below, rather than reflecting that it's actually Gmail:

```
  ALPINE 2.25   MESSAGE TEXT                                                                 Folder: baz(READONLY)                                                                 Message 1 of 1 TOP NEW  

Date: Mon, 27 Nov 2023 19:03:16 -0800
From: nicholas@mordor.saundersconsulting.tech
Subject: /home/nicholas/mail/baz

From english-personalized-digest@quora.com Wed, 25 Oct 2023 16:09:42
Delivered-To: saunders.nicholas@gmail.com
Received: by 2002:a05:6a20:8985:b0:17b:625d:d85c with SMTP id h5csp2678689pzg;
        Wed, 25 Oct 2023 09:09:51 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: AGHT+IHu6P59KuAHrRXJFUf0Ukb6yJsZvSJ/eJzoFX5Z0Ss6joX7NMCCGSLaMB+FjcYxYfXotEiX
X-Received: by 2002:a05:6214:d87:b0:66d:2491:6e69 with SMTP id e7-20020a0562140d8700b0066d24916e69mr15009888qve.36.1698250190804;
        Wed, 25 Oct 2023 09:09:50 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1698250190; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=t+B/5H3OG3U+gW27p1ombgYLIXgPRuQYNvjzAIfRfZsSqV+m1sUKAZmR1uZHL4oh3x
         TqGV5nNdo2URay8LV/RNcIRA6tcG821e2BHfkU1ZI0IwWVTYE3FoYHBx0b5gcl6B9pCe
         GI7zrMx9HrgiTtFwL+MU8ClDKLyfpPNU7XCkiyVKVL7IEsLpu8XKnLfe7LG7Ubrrk5y9
         g9lmzn6gGp5HnJ4XJtwCOhRVB7IdHw09Hsg+KHlDCiqtHQ9kp9Mbh1RWYKaxmaYIQR8j
         ALY1QctMg6CaM5NNMdAAyDvdPfZr5XuhVWSGva4XUQCXzduIbD3zE2f/fye35TiF5HNi
         DL1Q==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=message-id:date:list-unsubscribe:subject:to:from:mime-version
         :dkim-signature;
        bh=XwdWhbArMYNWlkx1JEC7s5sw6/1ncKpWbUlYF9l7s6I=;
        fh=Iz5slODCclxYRudGJ0OEA2//0cAQ4/t/JDf7SMpi3hY=;
        b=U/zrVueBcsA03+Viw7/4MNhXBW3Cxns5VwvFECNqbEp0peEVLu9+8eKQmJH1kbq3tO
         HLPx6/ynVlik5Kkq4LJnHD5R/qgkv8q0NUjDmQbFGQc9Wa0mVBzpFKyrFjIwGhJ1lfnD
         I32NX2QLHQp6KdgbDy2fBMjMPLqKmG1OCx2FRmC3+CpEcYovbRIUyx6qgr3aqiALkk7v
```

I'm not understanding what the problem is.  This should show as a list of e-mails, not as a single e-mail.  How can I make backup from Thunderbird to mbox for Alpine to read?

Why?

```
nicholas@mordor:~/mail$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/mail$ mail -f baz
Cannot create mailbox baz: Requested item not found
nicholas@mordor:~/mail$
```

Which seems odd.  The backup was just made from Thunderbird.